# Firebase how to sum field by users

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase database with a purchase object like this

```
purchase : {
    purchaseId1
    purchaseId2
    purchaseId3
}
```

Each my purchase are like this :

```
purchaseId1 : {
    user: userId1,
    price : 100 $
}
```

I use javascript firebase api to query some data and i want to return and object with the sums of price by userId , something like

```
purchaseOrdered : {
    {
    user: userId1,
    price : 3500 $
    }
    {
    user: userId2,
    price : 2300 $
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Show the code of how you are currently getting it without sums, so we can edit it.

Comment: For the moments i just get all purchase like this :   const snap = await firebase.database().ref('purchase').once('value')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to iterate through the object and add the price to a variable. Example:

```
var purchaseOrdered = {};
for (let object in purchase) {
   purchaseOrdered[object.userId].price += object.price;
}
```